# Struggling with MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `image` and `gradeReason`.  Each image is awarded a grade for it's quality and the user can select up 4 different reasons (`reasonID_1`, `reasonID_2`, `reasonID_3`, `reasonID_4`) by using selecting a `reasonID`.  The breakdown of the reason is stored in the `gradeReason` table.

```
image

imageID   auditID  reasonID_1  reasonID_2  reasonID_3  reasonID_4
-------   -------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1         123      1           13          7           3
2         124      8           13          8           6 
4         125      3           2           5           6
5         125      7           4           2           3

gradeReason

reasonID   category   name
--------   --------   ----
1          exposure   overexposed
2          exposure   underexposed
3          patient    patient moved
4          equipment  sensor too big
5          equipment  sensor too small
```

What I would like is a query that will return the number of times each reasonID has been used in an audit and what the name of gradeReason was

e.g.

audit 125 -

reasonID 3 was used twice - name 'patient moved',

reasonID 2 used twice - name 'underexposed'.

I'll be honest and say I have struggled with this for days and I can't even think where to begin.

Comment: I have been scribbling on bits of paper pseudo code trying to break it down because I'm assuming that it needs a subquery but that is where I get stuck, so actual sql code, nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is harder because your data is not properly normalized.  The following approach first normalizes the data, then does the join and aggregation:

```
select ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name, count(*) as cnt
from (select i.imageID, i.auditID,
             (case when n.n = 1 then ReasonID_1
                   when n.n = 2 then ReasonID_2
                   when n.n = 3 then ReasonID_3
                   when n.n = 4 then ReasonID_4
              end) as ReasonId
      from image i cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
           ) n
      ) ir join
      gradeReason gr
      on ir.ReasonId = gr.ReasonId
group by ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I don't understand how I get the information out of it I need.  I have tried adding WHERE ir.auditId = 13751316481858293091 after the group line but I get a sql syntax error

Comment: @tatty27 `WHERE` clause should be before `GROUP BY` clause... that's why you got a error

Answer (score 0):

For your select, you have to join gradeReason once for every foreign key to gradeReason:

```
    SELECT imageID
         , auditID
         , r1.name
         , r2.name
         , r3.name
         , r4.name
     FROM image i
LEFT JOIN gradeReason r1 on i.reasonID_1 = r1.reasonID
LEFT JOIN gradeReason r2 on i.reasonID_2 = r2.reasonID
LEFT JOIN gradeReason r3 on i.reasonID_3 = r3.reasonID
LEFT JOIN gradeReason r4 on i.reasonID_4 = r4.reasonID
```

Your example data is not sensible, as the foreign keys to gradeReason in your table image is not in gradeReason, but I guess you have more gradeReasons up your sleeve.

Moreover,your structure is not normalized:
gradeReason has duplicate entries in rows for category. This is not too bad, but it would be good practice to have a separate gradeReasonCategories table.

Comment: The purpose of the page this is so that users can add their own reasons, including their own categories etc.  The idea is the user creates their own reason, it's added to to the gradeReason table, and the reasonID is stored in the image table when they select that reason.  You are correct when you say that there are more reasons, I just put enough so that you see see the table layout.  Each of the reasonID values in the image table either have corresponding values in the image table or the reason hasn't yet been used by the user

Answer (score 0):

Another option using UNIONS:-

```
SELECT auditId, ReasonId, category, name, SUM(cnt)
FROM
(
    SELECT ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name, count(*) as cnt
    FROM image ir
    INNER JOIN gradeReason gr
    ON ir.reasonID_1 = gr.ReasonId
    WHERE ir.auditId = 123
    GROUP BY ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name, count(*) as cnt
    FROM image ir
    INNER JOIN gradeReason gr
    ON ir.reasonID_2 = gr.ReasonId
    WHERE ir.auditId = 123
    GROUP BY ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name, count(*) as cnt
    FROM image ir
    INNER JOIN gradeReason gr
    ON ir.reasonID_3 = gr.ReasonId
    WHERE ir.auditId = 123
    GROUP BY ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name, count(*) as cnt
    FROM image ir
    INNER JOIN gradeReason gr
    ON ir.reasonID_4 = gr.ReasonId
    WHERE ir.auditId = 123
    GROUP BY ir.auditId, gr.ReasonId, gr.category, gr.name
) Sub1
GROUP BY auditId, ReasonId, category, name
```